# Double cosets and conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let G be a group and $h,g \in G$ with $SgT=ShT$

Show that the subgroups $gTg^{-1}\cap S$ and $hTh^{-1}\cap S$ are conjugated in S.

Two subgroups $U,V$ are conjugated if $\phi(U)=gUg^{-1}=V$, right?

But i don't know how to use this in that case.

Some tips where nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say, but I suppose that $S$ and $T$ are subgroups of $G$.

You need to take an arbitrary element in $gTg^{-1}\cap S$, say $gtg^{-1} = s$, with $s\in S$ and $t\in T$, and show that there is an element $s_{1}\in S$ conjugating it to an element of $hTh^{-1}\cap S$.  (And conversely, of course.)

To this end, note that you can write $gt = sg$, so that $g = sgt^{-1}\in SgT = ShT$.  Therefore, there are elements $s_{1}\in S$ and $t_{1}\in T$ for which $g = s_{1}ht_{1}$. Now write
$$gtg^{-1} = s_{1}ht_{1}t(s_{1}ht_{1})^{-1}.$$
Can you re-arrange this to show that your original element $gtg^{-1}$ is conjugate, by an element of $S$, to some element in $hTh^{-1}\cap S$?

Once you've done that you can get the reverse inclusion either by symmetry or, explicitly, by interchanging the roles of $h$ and $g$.

Comment: $s=gtg^{-1}=s_1ht_1t((s_1)ht_1)^{-1}=s_1ht_1t(ht_1)^{-1}s_1^{-1}=s_1ht_1tt_1^{-1}h^{-1}s_1^{-1}$ Because $t_1tt_1^{-1} \in T$ $gtg^{-1}$ is conjugated in S by an element $hTh^{-1}$. I think we are finish here now. Maybe we can denote that the cut $gTg^{-1} \cap S$ is not empty, since S and T are subgroups of G, hence $e \in G$ is an element of the cut. Thank you! That helped!